# How to give a sketch of this new set?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Now I need to give the sketch of this set: $B = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2\le 4\}$ intersect with $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2\le 4y\}$. I guess that the first set is the interior of the circle of center $(0,0)$ and radius $2$ included its borders, isn't it? But the second set is not clear as well. may you help me please?

Comment: Look up "equation of a circle in standard form" (or general form?). You'll need to complete the square to determine the center and radius

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax Tutorial.  It's $x^2+(y-2)^2\le4$

Comment: Thanks I got it

Answer (score 0):

the second set is also a circle
just compare it with $x^2+y^2 +2gx+2fy+c=0$ where $g=0,f=-2
$ radius=$\sqrt{(g^2+f^2-c)}$
center=$(-g,-f)$ i.e.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).